# Why doesn't the coset (1,4,2,3)K belong to the Quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I had been given the following question and answer ( in the image)[image]

However i do not understand, why for example: (1,4,2,3)K does not belong the the quotient group?

Is there any faster way of finding all the cosets for H on a Symmetric group, rather than computing every single one? It takes a very long time for me to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, $(1,4,2,3)K$ *is* one of the elements of the quotient group. Where you're getting is confused is the fact that it is the very same element as $(1,3,2,4)K$ – we're just picking different representatives.

Comment: Is there any way to recognize this fact, other than trial and error of multiplying all elements of S by K, and seeing which give the same sets?

Comment: It can be shown that if two cosets share an element, they are the same coset. With this in mind, we know that one of the elements in the coset $(1,3,2,4)K$ is just $(1,3,2,4)$, having been composed with the identity in $K$, and it is easier to see that the cosets are the same just by observing that $(1,4,2,3)K\ni(1,4,2,3)(1,2)(3,4)=(1,3,2,4)\in (1,3,2,4)K$. These cosets share an element, so they must be the same. This lets you do a single computation instead of all of them.